# How to send Parse push notification at a specific time of day without using a date?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, parse-platform

Parse's docs for sending push notifications from cloud code states that the format looks like this:

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    push_time: new Date("2013-08-26T12:00:00"),
    data: {
       alert: "Local push notification"
    }
}, {
    success: function() {
        console.log("Successful push");
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

I may be misunderstanding this, but it looks like this will tell Parse to send out a push notification not only at **12:00:00** local time for all users, but also on the following date: **2013-08-26**.

What I want to do when the function runs, is to just send the notification at that local time, on whatever the date happens to be when the function runs. I'm not sure how to setup the syntax correctly to do this, as `push_time: new Date("T12:00:00");` doesn't seem to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have two answers to this that you can try. They both require you to specify the date and time, but the date aspect you can quickly set using tomorrow (or any day really).

First, using the native JavaScript SDK:

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
tomorrow.setHours(getRandomArbitrary(0,23),getRandomArbitrary(0,59),getRandomArbitrary(0,59));
var dayAfterTomorrow = new Date();
dayAfterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

Parse.Push.send({
    channels: [ "my channel" ],
    data: {
        alert: "push content here"
    },    
    push_time: tomorrow,
    expiration_time: dayAfterTomorrow
    }, {    
    success: function() {
        // Push was successful
        console.log("successfully sent push out");
        status.success("Push away!");
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // Handle error
        console.log("got an error");
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;    
}
```

Secondly, according to [this Parse post from a year ago](https://www.parse.com/questions/push-to-local-timezone-from-cloud-code), there is a bug in their SDK for JavaScript that won't do a local timezone push. You need to use their REST API:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": YOUR_APP_ID,
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": REST_API_KEY,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: {
    "where": query,
    "push_time": "2013-08-26T12:00:00", // format this as a STRING, not a Date Object
    "data": {    
      "alert": "Local push notification" 
    }
  },
  url: "https://api.parse.com/1/push"
}).then(function() {
  console.log("Successful push");
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I haven't tried the REST API code, but I do know the JavaScript SDK code works as I am using that in a project of mine. I'm not sure if it's sending local time to users or not, but that's not a requirement for the project I wrote.